# Is queues or rest apis a better approach to handle user requests?

Tags: java, rest, activemq-classic, load-balancing, mq

I have a requirement when multiple apps want to send notification out in the form of email.I want to have a central app where users send notification too and that central app converts to email and sends it. Should i use REST API's in between my central app to get notifications from other apps or use MQ where other apps can write and my app listens to it? which is a better approach and why?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! This question is likely to be closed due to it being a very broad question, as well as one where it is primarily opinion based. To that vain, here's some advice: Review the specifications for the functionality. Ask things like: What is the expected throughput? What are the acceptable parameters I have to operate in (are emails needing to be sent immediately, is a delay acceptable? If so, by how long and so forth) Do research on both options. Learn about MQ vs REST for request processing. Pick your solution based on that, and then ask a specific question here if you need.

Answer (score 2):

REST API <-> REST API are tightly coupled at *runtime*, and when you have multiple layers of services it can lead to cascading failures and complicated error handling scenarios. Additionally, one service can overrun another, causing a denial of service.

Whereas app -> q -> app connectivity is loosely coupled at runtime. When one system is down, the queue just fills up. Messaging systems also act as a natural buffer in the one-system-produces-too-fast scenario, b/c the second system is *consuming* data at the rate the second system can handle vs the rate at which the producer sends data.

That being said, sending query requests over messaging adds needless latency, as an API 'query' is effectively a polling-consume and the produce-to-fast and the cascading-failures problem are generally mitigated.

TLDR: You'll want both. API's for queries and messaging for commands. CQRS can be applied here:

C - command.. (create, save, delete, do some action, etc) send over messaging
Q - query.. (search, list, get, etc) send over API